# Finding the moment at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, moment

[image: Calculate the moment exerted on the nut by the spanner shown in the diagram.]

The question wants me to calculate the moment exerted on the nut, and the force (20 N) is applied at an angle (30 degrees) towards the pivot.

I tried redrawing this as a triangle, with an angle of 30, an opposite side of 20 N, and a hypotenuse of 0.24 m. I then placed another triangle next to that, and solved for that new triangle's hypotenuse, but got 23.1 N. By multiplying that by the distance from the pivot (0.24 m), it is clear that that's not the answer, as it doesn't match any of the answer choices.

Where did I go wrong, and what do I do now?

Comment: Asking homework-like question, we expect you to show us some effort. E.g. try to walk us through your ideas **why** you do this or that. The important point to understand is that the leverage and the force must be perpendicular to each another. Thus there must be some $cos(30°)$ involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it.

Resolve the $20N$ force along and *perpendicular* to the wrench. The torque is calculated from either

$$ \text{(torque)} = \text{(distance)} \times \text{(perpendicular force)} $$

or

$$ \text{(torque)} = \text{(perpendicular distance)} \times \text{(force)} $$

whichever one is easiest. They both come out numerically the same.

Comment: Didn't I already resolve the 20 N force perpendicular to the wrench?

Comment: @KreyLazory - no you didn't because the projection of a vector has to be _less_ that the original vector. In [this](https://i.imgur.com/nKqWaUa.png) triangle, if $y=20$ then how much is $x$?

Comment: Okay, I just did the trigonometry stuff wrong. It's all good now